# Extract profile picture from Facebook and store in Parse

Tags: facebook, image, parsing, save, profile

I managed to integrate Fb with Parse and able to login/sign up and populate the their name, email to parse. But when I try to retrieve the facebook picture and store into the database, it didn't work at all. My codes are as follows under makeMeRequest()  which I call after login process is done.

Appreciate your expert help on this (I have tried many methods I found from the web but none of them work). I don't know if I miss anything here. Appreciate a lor. Thanks.

```
private void makeMeRequest() {
    Request request = Request.newMeRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(),
            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(final GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        // Create a JSON object to hold the profile info
                        JSONObject userProfile = new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            // Populate the JSON object
                            userProfile.put("facebookId", user.getId());
                            userProfile.put("username", user.getName());

                            currentUser.setUsername(user.getFirstName());
                            currentUser.setEmail(user.asMap().get("email").toString());



                            AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> t = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>(){
                                protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... p) {
                                    Bitmap bm = null;
                                    try {
                                        URL aURL = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+ user.getId()+"/picture?type=large");
                                        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                                        conn.setUseCaches(true);
                                        conn.connect(); 
                                        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
                                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is); 
                                        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                                        bis.close(); 
                                        is.close();
                                    } catch (IOException e) { 
                                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                                    }
                                    return bm;
                                }

                                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bm){

                                        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
                                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                                        byteArray = FileHelper.reduceImageForUpload(byteArray);

                                        ParseFile file = new ParseFile("profile_pix", byteArray);
                                        currentUser.put(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE, file);


                                }
                            };
                            t.execute();    


                            try {
                                currentUser.save();
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }




                            // Show the user info
                            //updateViewsWithProfileInfo();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                        }

                    } else if (response.getError() != null) {
                        if ((response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_RETRY)
                                || (response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_REOPEN_SESSION)) {

                            //onLogoutButtonClicked();
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    request.executeAsync();

}
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but it looks as though you're actually trying to save the picture itself and not the link to the picture.  Facebook are quite happy for you to access a picture and use this in your authorized app, but you are not able to actually save the picture itself as a profile pic can change all the time and you don't actually have permission to store it.  If the user decided for whatever reason they didn't want the picture to be public any more they could take it down on FB, but you would still have a copy and they would have no knowledge of this.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks! :) I think you are right. I just pass the profile id to display then. Cheers!